# jquery html button gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

We are designing array of customized button which will be displayed as a gallery. User will pick from the gallery and customize different portion of the button and on changes different attribute preview will be shown.

Any idea how can we do it using jquery, html and jsp.

Comment: SO is not a code factory. It is here to help you with problems. Your first one is:

How do I provide my code to SO?

Comment: @JoakimM i am not finding source code from SO. I just entered here to get best possible idea. nothing else

Answer (score 0):

this should get you starting:

### HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="sub_border_size" value="-"/>
    <input type="button" id="add_border_size" value="+"/>
</div>

<div id="preview">
    <center>
        <input type="button" id="preview_button" value="button"/>
    </center>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#preview{
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    background:gray;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#preview_button{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
```

### JS

```
var border_size = 0;

$("#add_border_size").click(function(){
    border_size++;
    console.log(border_size);
    $("#preview_button").css("border",border_size+"px solid black");
});

$("#sub_border_size").click(function(){
    border_size--;
    console.log(border_size);
    $("#preview_button").css("border",border_size+"px solid black");
});
```

**fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/yPAM2/